# CheckedListBox result

Tags: powershell

I have a CheckedListBox in Powershell. When i select some checkbox the text result is empty.
When i select a second checkbox the first checkbox result text is displayed.

I use the following code for the CheckedListBox:

```
# Code
$ListView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
$ListView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$ListView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(533,325)
$ListView.CheckOnClick = $True
$ListView.Add_ItemCheck({
  for ($i = 0; $i - ($ListView.Items.Count-1); $i++)
  {
    if ($ListView.GetItemChecked($i))
    { 
    $s = $s + $ListView.Items[$i].ToString();
    }
  }

    Write-host $s

 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetItemChecked($i)` will only return the correct result for the item check that raised the event *after* the event handler has run.

You can [inspect the event arguments for the new value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666682/which-checkedlistbox-event-triggers-after-a-item-is-checked) of the item:

```
$ListView.Add_ItemCheck({

    param($sender,$e)

    $s = ""

    for ($i = 0; $i -le ($ListView.Items.Count-1); $i++)
    {
        # Check if $i is the index of the item we just (un)checked
        if($e.Index -eq $i)
        {
            # Inspect the new checked-state value
            if($e.NewValue -eq 'Checked')
            {
                $s += $ListView.Items[$i]
            }
        } 
        elseif ($ListView.GetItemChecked($i))
        { 
            # Item is already checked
            $s += $ListView.Items[$i]
        }
    }

    Write-host $s
})
```

Comment: Mathias, When i uncheck a box the text will not be removed. It will be removed when i uncheck a second box. Can you help me with this ???

Comment: @questhome yes, updated answer with `$e.NewValue -eq 'Checked'`