# Async sleep in loop

Tags: c#, async-await, wait

So for a project of mine I need to fetch values from a piece of hardware every 100 ms.
The fetching takes x amount of milliseconds.
So what I'm looking for but cannot find is a way to make sure a for/while always takes 100 ms (or more).

So in pseudo code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // Take measurements for 10 seconds
{
    // Call some async method that sleeps for 100 ms
    this.temperatureList.Add(this.HardwareManager.GetSensorValue(ESensor.Temperature)); // Takes 15 ms
    this.temperatureList.Add(this.HardwareManager.GetSensorValue(ESensor.Pressure)); // Takes 30 ms
    // await async method to finish
}
```

I have tried some async await things with this but I cannot seem to comprehend it.
Anyone who can help me find a reliable way to get 10 seconds of measurements with an interval of 100 ms?

EDIT:
I know that since I'm running C# on Windows, timing is not really a valid option. But this does not really matter in my question. My question is, how can I make sure the for loop takes at least(!!!) a 100 ms, while being as close as possible to 100 ms.

Comment: Use a timer with an interval of 100 perhaps?

Comment: How close do you need it to 100 ms? 100ms minus the time it takes to call the sensors?

Comment: Task.Delay(100)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: How about `Thread.Sleep(100);`? From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212966/how-can-i-put-a-delay-with-c)

Comment: Well, I need the loop to take around 100 ms, but fetching the values from the sensor can take between 5 and 25 ms, this is never exactly the same

Comment: `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp` and perhaps `TimeSpan.FromTicks` are your friends. See what time it is when you start the loop, do the expensive stuff, see what time it is now, sleep for `start + 100ms - now`

Comment: What do you mean by "async" in this context? An async sleep is done using `await Task.Delay(sleepMillisecs)`

Comment: Do bear in mind that timers on Windows are horrendously inaccurate, and that's just the reality of a non-realtime operating system. You're lucky to be accurate to tens of ms, and there will be random delays which are way above 100ms

Comment: use a [stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1), do your measures, get the time elapsed and wait for `100 - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Timer for Millisecond Waits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891879/c-sharp-timer-for-millisecond-waits)

Comment: Guys, I do know that since I'm running windows, timing is not a good thing, I know that sleep of 100 ms is at least 100 ms. But I want to know how to perform this sort of action by running some kind of async sleep, if possible without uses of stopwatches.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `Stopwatch`? Windows has some very high-accuracy timers, and `Stopwatch` is the API you use to access them (which is perhaps slightly unintuitive, but that's how it is)

Comment: This answer might be helpful: [Run async method regularly with specified interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval/62724908#62724908). For completing after 10 seconds you could include a `Stopwatch` in the logic, or use a `CancellationToken` that will be canceled after 10 seconds (method [`CancelAfter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to create a Stopwatch and just wait for it to reach the next milestone after doing each operation.

The benefit of this way is that:

- You will add the overhead of the loop into the mix, adjusting your delay to compensate
- As such, it should have little to no "drifting" (where operations will get progressively "later" according to when they should've happened)

Sort of like this:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
long next = 100;
while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 10000)
{
    // do your operation here
    long left = next - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    if (left > 0)
        await Task.Delay((int)left);
    next += 100;
}
```

Due to the accuracy of things, your operations will *around* each 100 milliseconds, but they shouldn't drift.

If you're OK with tying up a thread for the duration of those 10 seconds, you could switch out the delay part with `Thread.Sleep`:

```
if (left > 0)
    Thread.Sleep((int)left);
```

It will run your operations closer to the 100 millisecond mark, but might still have a slight overhead due to the fact that `Thread.Sleep` has some overhead as well.

If you're OK with "burning CPU", you can do this instead:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var next = 100;
while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 10000)
{
    // do your operation here
    
    while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < next) ;
    next += 100;
}
```

This will run your operation even closer to the actual 100 milliseconds mark, as `Task.Delay` and `Thread.Sleep` will have overhead that will tend to delay just slightly longer than what you intended. It will, however, tie up a CPU core for the duration of those 10 seconds.

Comment: This looks quite promising! Of course the burning CPU can be less when placing an await Task.Delay(1) inside.

Comment: If you're going to put an `await Task.Delay(1)` inside a while loop, you're better off with the first part of the answer, which uses a single `Task.Delay`

Comment: Adding  `await Task.Delay(1)` will give you the same "around 100 milliseconds" inaccuracy as the first part. Perhaps using `Thread.Sleep(...)` in those cases will have less overhead. You would then tie up a thread for 10 seconds, but not a whole CPU.