# How i can use PictureBox.Visible with Delay?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void hide()
{
  pictureBox1.Visible = true;
  pictureBox2.Visible = true;
}

private void kontrol()
{
  hide();
  //i want to work that hide () with 1 second delay ? How its possible?    
}
```

[Delayed function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545533/delayed-function-calls)
I tried all ways in this topic, always error

Comment: You need to use a timer and / or a queue. The linked question is a good start. What errors do you get?

Comment: `always error`  Show us the code that produced the error, and tell us the error.  You would get better help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use async / await in a func Like This :

```
  private async void kontrol()
  {
   pictureBox1.Visible = false;
   pictureBox2.Visible=false;
   await Task.Delay(1000);
   pictureBox1.Visible = true;
   pictureBox2.Visible=true;
 }
```

Comment: You are Welcome :)